# How to turn off Eclipse auto expanded my project folders?

Tags: eclipse, directory, project, expand

I'm developing in Android (not sure if that matters) on a sustaining project at work.  I have a very large project with too many files in each folder.  Every time I click on an opened file's tab in the source code editor, Eclipse automatically opens the folder where the file is located.  How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but in the sidebar (package explorer) there is a button at the top that is 2 yellow arrows pointing towards each other. You should click this to stop the editor auto syncing the explorer. It is a persisting button click so you click once to enable the feature and again to disable it.

Comment: It is "Link with Editor" button

Answer (score 0):

For me worked click on "Focus on active task".